# Help with inverse in non-linear function

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

while I was studying a problem in multivariative calculus, I was faced by this: Find the inverse of $f(x,y) = (\sin(xy),x\cos(y))$. If we call $u = \sin(xy)$ and $v = x\cos(y)$ how to solve this system for $x$ and $y$? I cant get anything, the best I've got was
$$
\frac{y}{\cos(y)} = \frac{arcsin(u)}{v},
$$
but I cant proceed. Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hint: $xy = \arcsin u$ and $y=\arccos v$.

Comment: @Greg Martin Thank you, but is true that $y= \arccos v$? Because looks like $y = \arccos(v/x)$ and then the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry, you're right of course, I misread the problem. It seems unlikely to have a closed-form solution.

Comment: @GregMartin, yes, but I need to calculate the derivative of the local inverse. Do you know some way that I don't need to explicit the inverse itself? Because the Inverse Function theorem doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Oh, then you'd be looking for "implicit differentiation" I suppose, but a two-variable version.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, that's right. That endded up with 3 equation systems, that I've solved with WolframAlpha (The site itself took a lot to calculate it).